# Date Extracting from a website using Python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, data-science

```
# Find string between two strings
def find_between( s, first, last ):
     try:
         start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
         end = s.index( last, start )
         return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
         return ""

from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import html
import requests

link = "https://www.calendar-12.com/catholic_holidays/2019"
response = urlopen(link)
content = response.read().decode("utf-8") 


table = find_between(content, "<tbody>","</tbody>");
rows = table.split("/tr")
csv = "Day\n"
for row in rows:
    day = find_between(row, '">', "</t")
    day = find_between(day, "> ", "</")
    csv = csv + day + "\n"

print(csv)
```

This code suppose to extract date from the website but it doesn't, can you help to solve the problem. the only output is Day

Comment: Please show the function `find_between`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this should do it:

```
import lxml.html as lh
import requests

link = "https://www.calendar-12.com/catholic_holidays/2019"
req = requests.get(link)

doc= lh.fromstring(req.text)
tab = doc.xpath('//table')[0]
rows = []
for t in tab.xpath('.//tr[@class]//td/a'):
    row = []
    row.extend(t.text.strip().replace('day,','day,xxx').split('xxx'))
    rows.extend(row)
    
for day,date,holiday in zip(rows[0::3],rows[1::3],rows[2::3]):
    print(day,date,holiday)
    #EDIT:
    #or to store these in variables:
    a,b,c = day,date,holiday
    print(a,b,c)
```

Output:

```
Tuesday,  January 1, 2019 Solemnity of Mary, Mother of God
Sunday,  January 6, 2019 Epiphany
Tuesday,  March 5, 2019 Shrove Tuesday (Mardi Gras)
Wednesday,  March 6, 2019 Ash Wednesday
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you for your solution, but how to store the result in a variable.

Comment: @GBU-43BNAVY See edit; that should to it, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: I need to create a dataset of day and date(day,date) from the calendar of the website. How can I create a dataset from the output of the for loop. I appreciate If you can help me on this.

Comment: Or How can I add day, date after each loop to a list or string, which I can use it to create a dataset later.

Comment: @GBU-43BNAVY  I think the best way to handle it is to post it as a separate question.